# telerik radscheduler Appointments don't update with ruler change

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, telerik-scheduler

In my application I want to give the user the ability to see that start and end date of the radscheduler control.

I found I can do this using the following code

```
RulerPrimitive ruler = (this.scheduler.SchedulerElement.ViewElement as SchedulerDayViewElement).DataAreaElement.Ruler;
ruler.StartScale = 5
ruler.EndScale = 9
```

After I add the code, the ruler will adjust but the appointments start and end times will no longer align with the appropriate time on the ruler. The telerik docs don't mention anything else that need to get called, so I am wondering what I am missing?

Comment: What do you mean by "the appointments start and end times will no longer align with the appropriate time on the ruler". Are you expecting the appointment start/end times to be changed according to the new ruler scale?

Comment: @checho no, but I would expect the appointment block to re-align with the ruler scale markings as the scale is adjusted. This is not happening. Example by default the ruler scale is hourly. if i change it to half hour, the ruler scale changes but the appointment stays in the exact same position on the screen, thus making the appointment appear like it occurs before it actually does.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need the [exact time rendering functionality of the Telerik UI for WinForms RadScheduler](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/scheduler-views-exact-time-rendering.html). Here is how to turn it on:

```
radScheduler1.EnableExactTimeRendering = true;
```